# Proxy causing the send SMS function not working

Tags: c#, proxy, sms-gateway

I'm creating a send SMS function that required proxy to work but when i tested it does not seems to working. Is there another way to da this or did i code it wrongly?

[The proxy function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kInxK.png)
[The send SMS function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s8qk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to [Troubleshoot](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) Proxy Issues Causing the Send SMS [Function](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) to Not Work

[Introduction](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc): Why is My Send SMS [Function](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) Not Working?

keywords: [proxy][], sms, send sms, text message

1. Check Your [Network](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) Connection
2. [Verify](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) that the Number You're Trying to Text is Valid
3. If It's a Cell [Phone](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc), Make Sure the Carrier is Set [Correctly](https://youtu.be/q0m8OUFVuVc) on the Remote Server Settings Page
4. Make Sure Your Device has a Data Connection and You're Connected to WiFi

keywords: cell phone not sending messages, device not sending messages, sms not working

Conclusion: The Cause of this Issue Can Vary but Generally it's Due to a Proxy Issue with Sending Outbound Messages or an Error Occuring Between Steps 1-3

Comment: How about the code ? Am i coded it correctly?

Comment: yes its right carry on

Comment: Thanks Rafin. You are right i did found mistake in the phone number and now its working fine.